# "Permission denied" error when trying to create shapefile layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers

I'm not super familiar with QGIS as I am used to ArcGIS. But when I try to create a new shapefile layer, I keep getting an error that says:

> Layer creation failed: Failed to create file vacancies.shp: Permission
> denied.

Right now I am working off an OSM Standard layer and a shapefile I downloaded from the ArcGIS website. What might be wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without more information, perhaps including a screen shot might offer more clues. However an initial guess is that you're trying to save the file somewhere you don't have write access privileges. Are you working on a personal computer? Try saving the file somewhere you can normally save things.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the button on the right with the 3 dots?
The field is a file path. If you enter only the name of your file in the field, it will try to create the layer at the root folder of your system, where you usually don't have rights to write.

[image: filepath]

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to save the file under my desktop. Here is the screenshot. When I hit "OK", it created a new layer called "GIS" under my layers, so I guess it worked! Thank you
[image: screenshot]